# "Il y a combien de temps" vs "Depuis combien de temps"

Tags: indications-de-temps, questions

Je comprends la différence entre "il y a" et "depuis" pour parler de temps, par exemple:

> J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans. J'habite à Londres depuis 5 ans.

Quand on dit "il y a", c'est une chose qui a commencé dans le passé et qui a fini dans le passé tandis que "depuis" est une chose qui a commencé dans le passé mais qui est encore dans le présent.

Dans mon exemple, je n'habite plus à Sheffield parce que j'ai déménagé à Londres il y a 5 ans et j'habite à Londres depuis 5 ans (c'est à dire, j'habite encore à Londres).

Mon doute est : j'ai déjà entendu beaucoup de gens dire "il y a combien de temps ..." et "depuis combien de temps ..." et j'ai eu l'impression qu'il n'y avait pas de différences entre par exemple :

> Il y a combien de temps qu'il est ici ?
>
> Depuis combien de temps est-il ici ?
>
> Il y a combien de temps que tu attends ?
>
> Depuis combien de temps attends-tu ?

Je pense que les 4 phrases ci-dessus sont correctes et qu'il n'y pas de différences entre elles. Est-ce que quelqu'un peut confirmer ? S'il y a des différences, est-ce que vous pouvez m'expliquer svp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. *Depuis* et *il y a*  expriment une durée

Les phrases :

> J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans.
> J'habite à Londres depuis 5 ans.

sont correctes mais le raisonnement grammatical qui suit est partiellement faux.

**a)**
*Il y a* et *depuis* peuvent tous les deux exprimer une action qui a commencé dans le passé et qui a fini dans le passé.
Les deux phrases qui suivent sont correctes et hors contexte peuvent exprimer la même chose :

> J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans.
> J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans.

Mais :

> J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans.

est clair et sans ambiguïté.

Alors que :

> J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans.

n'indique pas que tu n'es pas reparti y habiter depuis.

Par contre on peut aussi dire :

> Il y a 5 ans que j'ai quitté Sheffield.

ce qui permet de lever l'ambiguïté.

**b)**
Avec le présent on peut dire aussi bien :

> Il y a 5 ans que j'habite à Londres.

que

> J'habite à Londres depuis 5 ans.

*Il y a* et *depuis* peuvent tous les deux exprimer une **durée**. *Il y a* ne peut qu'exprimer une durée, *depuis* peut exprimer une durée ou le point de départ de l'action dans le temps.

> J'habite à Londres depuis 2004.

#### 2.  *Depuis* et *il y a* sont utilisés indifféremment tous les deux pour poser des questions sur la durée

« Combien de temps » représente la durée inconnue qui doit être quantifiée dans la réponse.
Le sens de la question sera le même, que l'on utilise *depuis* ou *il y a*, par contre la structure de la phrase sera différente vu que l'expression *il y a* est une expression idiomatique verbale et qu'elle peut porter la marque de  la question.

**a)  Questions avec *depuis***
Toutes les constructions interrogatives suivantes sont correctes :

> Depuis combien de temps as-tu quitté Sheffield ?
> Depuis combien de temps est-ce que tu as quitté Sheffield ?
> Depuis combien de temps est-il ici ?
> Depuis combien de temps est-ce qu'il est ici ?
> Depuis combien de temps attends-tu ? /est-ce que tu attends ?

À l'oral, ou dans un écrit plutôt familier, le français accepte l'absence de la marque grammaticale de la question (inversion du sujet ou emploi de *est-ce-que*) et la question est donc indiquée par la ponctuation à l'écrit, ton exemple :

> Depuis combien de temps il est ici ?
> Depuis combien de temps tu attends ?

et par l'intonation à l'oral.

À noter que ce que tu proposes ci-dessous ne peut pas se dire :

> <del>Depuis combien de temps que tu attends ?</del>

Par contre tu as peut-être déjà entendu :

> Ça fait combien de temps que tu attends ?

où l'utilisation de « Ça fait... » entraîne l'emploi de « que ».

**b)  Questions avec *il y a***

> Combien de temps y a-t-il que tu as quitté Sheffield ?
> Combien de temps est-ce qu'il y a que tu as quitté Sheffield ?

Peut se dire, mais c'est lourd et on ne l'utilisera pas spontannément, alors que à l'oral, la question sans l'inversion du sujet est habituelle :

> Il y a combien de temps qu'il est ici ?
> Il y a combien de temps que tu attends ?
> Il y a combien de temps que tu as quitté Sheffield ?

Pour les questions il faut noter l'utilisation possible de *depuis quand* à la place de *depuis combien de temps* :

> Depuis quand est-ce que tu attends ?
> Depuis quand attends-tu ?
> Tu attends depuis quand ?

Dans ce cas la réponse peut porter soit sur une durée, soit sur le point de départ de l'action, alors que quand on utilise *depuis combien de temps*, on s'attend plutôt à avoir une durée dans la réponse (depuis, deux minute, depuis longtemps, etc.)

Comment: Super ! Merci :)

Comment: Honnêtement, *J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans* m'accroche un peu l'oreille. Peut-être que c'est ma cure d'anglais qui m'a déformé, mais pour moi l'OP avait raison pour la différence entre *depuis* et *il y a* dans cette phrase.

Comment: @Joffrey @Laure `J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans.`? Dans le livre «Nouvelle Grammaire du Français» (par Y. Delatour, etc, Hachette Livre, 2004), il est écrit que: *Ne dites pas* `Je l'ai rencontré depuis deux ans.`. On dit: Je **ne** l'ai **pas** rencontré depuis deux ans.

Comment: @FrankScience Oui pour moi la phrase *J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans.* n'est pas très correcte, du moins a l'usage ca me gêne. Par contre, je dirais volontier *Je n'ai pas vu Sheffield depuis 5 ans*, ou *J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans*.
En fait, l'usage de *il y a* ne porte pour moi que sur un événement ponctuel (comme quitter un lieu) et * depuis*  porte sur qqch qui dure (comme habiter quelque part).

Comment: Juste pour clarifier, aucune des 3 phrases *"J'ai quitté Sheffield depuis 5 ans.", "J'ai quitté Sheffield il y a 5 ans.", "Il y a 5 ans que j'ai quitté Sheffield."* ne sous-entend un retour la bas. Je dirais même presque le contraire, suivant le contexte.

Comment: @Joffrey Vous avez raison, bien que la règle expliquée dans le livre (loc. cit.) soit plus compliquée: si notre phrase au passé composé se construit avec "être", alors on peut dire "depuis". Comme: je suis passé au couloir depuis cinq minutes. (Je ne sais pas s'il est correcte. Je vais lire le livre ce soir pour préciser.)

Comment: @FrankScience Il doit certainement y avoir des règles plus précises en effet. Ceci étant dit, en tant que natif, je fonctionne plutôt à l'usage de la langue (ce que j'entends tous les jours). En l'occurrence, *"Je suis parti de Sheffield depuis 5 ans"* sonne toujours bizarre à mes oreilles, malgré l'auxiliaire *être*, mais c'est peut-être juste moi, il faudrait l'avis d'autres natifs.

Comment: @Joffrey Dans le livre (loc. cit.): à 1. le présent ou l'imparfait; 2. le passé composé ou le plus-que-parfait:  a. avec l'auxiliaire *être*; b. négatif avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*; c. quelques verbes avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*: grandir, augmenter, progresser, grossir, etc, ou commencer, finir, quitter, disparaître. Peut-être ce livre ne s'accorde pas toujours avec l'utilisation quotidienne: un [exemple](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/23819/7823).

Comment: @Joffrey Deux exemples pour l'utilisation de *être* dans le livre: Allô! Est-ce que je peux parler à Paul? Non, désolé, il **est parti depuis** une demi-heure. (= il n'est plus là); Les élèves **étaient arrivés depuis** une semaine en classe de nature quand il a enfin cessé de pleuvoir. (= ils étaient là depuis une semaine)

Answer (score 4):

Ton analyse de départ est correcte, ce sont certains de tes exemples qui, pris dans le registre courant voire familier, sont moins "académiques".

Formes qu'on accepterait dans un écrit scolaire ou professionnel :

> Depuis combien de temps est-il ici ?
>
> Depuis combien de temps est-ce que tu attends ?

Formes plus ou moins dérivées vers le langage de tous les jours :

> Tu attends depuis combien de temps ?
>
> Depuis combien de temps tu attends ?
>
> T'attends depuis combien de temps ?
>
> Il y a combien de temps que tu attends ?

voire

> Ça fait (depuis) combien de temps que t'attends ?

Comment: Je suis principalement d'accord, mais j'enlèverais le *depuis* dans le dernier exemple, ça me paraît plus correct (et aussi plus utilisé).