# L'utilisation de «se faire» et «se laisser» au sens passif?

Tags: expressions, passif, constructions-causatives

On dit:

> Christian s'est fait voler son portable.

En revanche, on ne peut pas dire ou écrire:

> Le portable de Christian s'est fait voler.

Pourquoi est-ce interdit?

Dans le livre «Nouvelle Grammaire du Français» (Hachette Livre, 2004), il est écrit que:

> Se faire et se laisser + infinitif
>
> Le sujet est toujours un animé. L'agent n'est pas toujours exprimé.

Mais en fait, on voit beaucoup de constructions «se faire sentir» dont les sujets sont inanimés. Pour autant, je voudrais me renseigner à propos des règles exactes d'utilisation de «se faire» et «se laisser».

Comment: Une personne se fait voler quelque chose. **Une chose (le portable) ne peut pas se faire voler quelque chose**. Une personne se laisse dire la verité, mais Une chose ne peut pas se laisser dire la verité. Les choses ne parlent pas (sauf dans un language poétique). Lá on voit clairement pourquoi.

Answer (score 2):

En règle générale, la forme passive décrit un état et non une action.
On trouvera donc:

> Le portable de Christian a été volé.

Cela étant la conséquence de la première phrase sous forme active.
Pour la précision, on devrait probablement utiliser le passé simple, mais cela sonne "vieux" aujourd'hui.

Comment: Est-ce que toutes les formes passives décrivent des états ? *La voiture était conduite par un chauffard.*, *cette position était défendue par des canons.*

Comment: Ces deux exemples avec la voiture et la position me paraissent effectivement être un état, ou en tout cas une propriété.